# Copy and paste a pose onto a different character

Tags: animation, pose-mode

I have a rigged character and in pose, I ve made a new body and rigged it and now I would like to copy the pose of the other character. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the bones have the same names :

Select the first armature. In Pose mode, select all bones. In the Dope Sheet, select all the keys, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.

Select the second armature, pose mode, select all bones. **Add a keyframe on the same channels used in the first pose** (like LocRot or LocRotScale). In the Dope sheet, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd>.

Comment: Yes but its not animated there are no keys it is just posed

Comment: and bones are not same names will it not work? i have a daz character posed fbx imported with its bones being slightly different to metarig

Comment: If the name are different, it won't work. To copy a pose, just select all your bones in Pose mode then Ctrl+C.